# What's wrong with this JSF EL statement?

Tags: java, jsf, el

Code

```
<c:if test="#{attr1 && !attr2 && (empty attr3)}">
```

Error returned

> The entity name must immediately
>   follow the '&' in the entity
>   reference.

I simply need to check if attribute 1 is true, attribute 2 is false and attribute 3 is not set.
Tried without parentheses on first chance, same result.

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It expects entity name, like **&amp**;. You can use **&amp**; **&amp**; or replace it with **and** for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the behavior you're seeing is that `&` is a reserved character in XML. Replace with `&amp` or `and` like n0weak advised.